# How to check if 2 elements displayed on the same row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming I have 2 elements on a responsive design like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

both of them with style contains:

```
width: auto;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
```

And because I'm expecting different screen sizes to view page, so, according to screen size, sometimes they will be rendered/displayed on the same row, and sometimes they will not!, the second DIV will be moved to a separate row.

So, I'm wondering, how can I check if they are on the same line with JavaScript?

Thank you

Comment: You need to ask your question with more details. Try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you @AliSeyfi , question updated now!

Comment: I don't know a specific answer, but take a look at https://api.jquery.com/position/.  Using this, you should be able to tell the vertical postion offset of your parent container for both divs and compare.  If it is the same, the are on the same row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"on the same line" would require inline elements or floating block elements of the exact same height. DIVs are block elements by default. So either use `<span>` tags instead of `<div>`, or add `display: inline-block;`to the CSS rule of those DIVs

ADDITION after EDIT OF QUESTION:

`width: auto` for a `<div>` means 100% of the parent element (in this case full width). As I wrote: If you have blocks, use `display: inline-block;` in their CSS. If you want them to have the same height, put them into a common container DIV (which you already have) and apply the following CSS:

```
#container {
  display: table;
}
.first, .second {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Aha (edited question), Javascript: Well, read out the DIV widths, add them and compare the result to the (read-out) container width.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the element bounding boxes and check for overlap:

```
var rect1 = $('.first')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
var rect2 = $('.second')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
var overlaps = rect1.top <= rect2.bottom && rect2.top <= rect1.bottom;
```

This checks for any overlap which will probably be sufficient for your use. I used jQuery to get the elements but you can use pure js in the same way, it would just be a bit more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of line on a page. You can check the x and y position of any element in the window and then decide if that meets whatever criteria you have for **"on the same line"**.

By default, a div is the full width of a window so the two divs inside your container in this HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

will be one above the other unless there is some other CSS you have not disclosed that controls the layout to allow them to be in the same row.  If they are indeed `width: auto` and don't have any other layout rules affecting this, then they will each be full width and thus `first` will be above `second` in the layout stream.  They would never be "on the same line" by any typical definition of that phrase.

Feel free to try it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/y0k7hLr8/ by resizing the right pane to any width you want.  In all cases, the `first` will stay on top of the `second`.

---

If, on the other hand, you allow the `div` elements to have a different type of layout such as let them be `display: inline-block` and define a width for them, then the layout engine will fit as many on a given row as possible like here: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/229rs97p/

Comment: yes, I'm aware about this point, and they're already with `display: inline-block;` , sorry for didn't mention that on my question from the begining.... I'm NOT asking: "how can I make them on the same row", I'm asking: how can I tell if they're on same row? with javascript... sorry again for not being clear!

Answer (score -2):

Something tells me display: flex might help you in this.  Read https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for more info.